# Recorrer toda una columna, saltando espacios vacíos en VBA

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-office

Hola buenos días a todos.

Tengo un form que traspasa la información de un archivo de excel a otro, al momento del traspaso hay una validación que quita "mm" y deja únicamente los números.

Pero tengo un problema, hay algunos espacios vacíos en estas columnas, en los espacios en vacíos, este se detiene. Por lo cual no hace el recorrido completo y no quita "mm" de todos los datos.

Lo que intento es saber como brincar un espacio en blanco para seguir con el calculo.

[image: EJEMPLO]

En esta imagen podemos ver como va quitando correctamente "mm" de los datos, pero al encontrarse con un espacio en blanco, se detiene.

```
dim delete_K 

delete_K = 2
           Do While Workbooks("E2_E1B_SIZE_SELECT 7Sep21Automatizado (version 1).xlsm").Worksheets("PRINCIPAL").Cells(delete_K, "K").Value <> ""
             Workbooks("E2_E1B_SIZE_SELECT 7Sep21Automatizado (version 1).xlsm").Worksheets("PRINCIPAL").Cells(delete_K, "K").Value = CStr(Replace(Workbooks("E2_E1B_SIZE_SELECT 7Sep21Automatizado (version 1).xlsm").Worksheets("PRINCIPAL").Cells(delete_K, "K").Value, "mm", ""))
           Loop
```

El código anterior es el código que estoy utilizando.

Según tengo entendido, esto lo podría solucionar con algo como esto:

```
NumRows = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Pero no logro solucionar esto, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.
Buen día. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así debería funcionarte:

```
Sub test()
Dim delete_K As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim LR As Long


With Workbooks("E2_E1B_SIZE_SELECT 7Sep21Automatizado (version 1).xlsm").Worksheets("PRINCIPAL")
    LR = .Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'última celda no vacía de la columna K
    For i = 2 To LR Step 1
        .Range("K" & i).Value = CStr(Replace(.Range("K" & i).Value, "mm", ""))
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```